# How to create dummy column with ```yyyy-mm-dd``` format in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to create a dummy column with the `yyyy-mm-dd` format in pandas? I want to change the `index` column to the `2000-01-01` format and auto-fills the rest.
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `index` column to a [**`pd.date_range()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) using the `start` and `periods` params:

```py
df['index'] = pd.date_range(start='2000-01-01', periods=len(df))

#           index  raw
# 0    2000-01-01  169
# 1    2000-01-02  146
# 2    2000-01-03  161
# 3    2000-01-04  115
# 4    2000-01-05  185
# ...         ...  ...
# 1409 2003-11-10  177
# 1410 2003-11-11  156
# 1411 2003-11-12  144
# 1412 2003-11-13  101
# 1413 2003-11-14  109
```